# How do you configure Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) to use fstab to automatically mount a Windows Network File Share?

Tags: linux, windows-10, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cifs

I'm trying to mount a windows share (SMB/CIFS) using a Debian 10 linux distribution running on Windows 10's Subsystem for Linux using fstab to automount on startup. My software specs are

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro 21H2
OS Build: 19044.1526
    
Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)
Distribution: Debian 10.11
```

According to the following article by Microsoft, you can create a text file at `/etc/wsl.conf` to store user configuration settings for WSL2.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config

I started using *wsl.conf* to set the **mountFsTab** key to true. That should ensure that WSL processes the fstab file. I know the setting should not matter because it defaults to true, but I wanted to make sure it was set to true. My *wsl.conf* file currently looks like:

```
# Automatically mount Windows drive when the distribution is launched. 
[automount]
# Automatically mount the fixed drives (C:) under /mnt.
enabled = false
# Sets the `/etc/fstab` file to be processed when a WSL distribution is launched.
mountFsTab = true
        
# Network host settings that enable the DNS server used by WSL 2. This example changes the hostname, sets generateHosts to false, preventing WSL from the default behavior of auto-generating /etc/hosts, and sets generateResolvConf to false, preventing WSL from auto-generating /etc/resolv.conf, so that you can create your own (ie. nameserver 1.1.1.1).
[network] 
hostname = JTI-ITL05-DEBIAN
```

The **hostname** does change successfully. However, even when the **mountFsTab** key is set to true, the *fstab* file’s mounts are not being applied when the Debian WSL2 instance starts. To test the *fstab* file, I first tried running the following command.

```
Sudo mount -a
```

The command successfully mounts the two entries I have in `/etc/fstab`. Here is an example of my *fstab* entries to illustrate the structure using the **DrvFs** file system plugin Microsoft created for WSL.

```
#file system                    dir            type    options                         dump    pass
\\\\domain.com\\share\\path     /mnt/mountdir  drvfs   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000      0       0
C:                              /mnt/c         drvfs   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000      0       0
```

To test the processing of fstab, I included a line to mount a local device, drive C in Windows. The line that mounts a local device, mounts successfully when the WSL2 instance starts up. The other line pointing to a Windows network share does not mount on startup, but I can mount it after the instance boots to a terminal CLI. I can confirm the results using the **wsl** command to shutdown the instance and start it back up. The fstab file is being processed on start up.

I don’t see a relevant log file in `/var/log` to check for errors. All of my tests have failed so far to get the fstab file to mount a Windows network share when WSL2 Debian starts up.

How do I get the WSL2 instance to automatically mount a Windows network share found in the fstab file?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on my systems at this point.  I was thinking maybe `/etc/fstab` was getting processed before `init` installed 9p and virtio into the instance.  But on both my Windows 10 and Windows 11 systems, the share mounted when WSL started, both from a `wsl --terminate <distro>` and even a `wsl --shutdown`.  It *could* still be a timing issue on your system.  Check `dmesg` to see if there are any hints there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out I did set everything up correctly. To answer the original question, follow the procedure below to configure Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) to use fstab to automatically mount a Windows Network File Share.

1. Open WSL2 in a terminal.
2. Create a directory to mount the file share. `/mnt/mountdir`
3. Create a file called "fstab". `/etc/fstab`
4. Add the following line to the "fstab" file.

```
\\\\domain.com\\share\\path    /mnt/mountdir    drvfs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000    0    0
```

Fill in the share path with a windows share on your network.

I setup a new laptop running Windows 10, followed the procedure above, and confirmed that the Windows share is mounted when the WSL2 instance starts. I'm not sure what the original issue was. It seems to be related to Windows 10 OS corruption. I'll update my answer if I can find the original cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `fstab` to mount automatically at boot.

Change

```
\\\\domain.com\\shares\\sharename   /mnt/mntdir drvfs       uid=1000,gid=1000   0       0
```

To

```
\\\\domain.com\\shares\\sharename   /mnt/mntdir drvfs       defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000   0       0
```

While `auto` would be enough, `defaults` would contain the following options:

```
 defaults
          Use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

Comment: I tried adding either "defaults" or "auto" to the list of comma-separated options. I made sure to shutdown and stop the WSL2 instance to test fstab. Unfortunately, neither changes made any difference for me. The "fstab" file was still not processed on startup, but I can use mount command to mount the fstab entries. I'll add the "defaults" option to my post to illustrate that I tried that out.

Comment: What are the permissions for your wsl.conf and fstab files set to? I can't get fstab to execute with settings similar to what you have above.