# How to permanently mount directory in WSL2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount

I have a folder on Windows
`C:/Users/macie/dev`
and I want to mount it on `/home/maciek/dev` on WSL (Ubuntu).
It stops working after restarting Windows. How do I make the mount permanent?

Here's my `/etc/fstab file`:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
/mnt/c/Users/macie/dev /home/maciek/dev        none    bind
```

I used `sudo mount --bind -o default` too.

Comment: This might be relevant for you: [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2636)

Comment: Also, [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1710001/1210833), which for some reason I'm unable to use as a "dupe" target.  Apologies - I was about to point you to this one in your Stack Overflow question, but it got migrated (my fault for voting too early) while I was typing the comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you configure Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) to use fstab to automatically mount a Windows Network File Share?](https://superuser.com/questions/1710001/how-do-you-configure-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2-to-use-fstab-to-automa)

Answer (score 2):

While I am not familiar with WSL, I realized that you are missing a few options in your fstab. Also you did not specify a filesystem type. Judging from [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2636), it seems that you need to specify `drvfs` if you want to mount a directory from your windows installation.

Try the following:

```
/mnt/c/Users/macie/dev /home/maciek/dev drvfs defaults,bind 0 0
```

And test with `mount -a` then restart and check if it worked.

Comment: It works after restart after using sudo mount -a. Partial victory, but thanks for your help